# Vue access data from parent if using runtime compiler

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

Im working on a project with vuejs and the goal is to render html received from a server which can include custom vue components. These components need access to a shared context object to fetch data of their own. Im rendering this html using vues compile function. To get the data into the child components im aware of two ways of doing it...

- 1: replacing part of the html (which does not include any binding like `<component :props="var" />` just the `<component />`)
- 2: accessing it from the child component using this.$parent.context

I am quite sure that the second way is not the "vue way of doing things". Im interested in any ideas how to solve the problem in a more elegant way.